# Ajax request sending only part of data to PHP server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send an array of objects (Which I succesfully extract from a Handsontable) to a script in my PHP server.

```
function saveMaterials(showAlert){
    var tableData = handsontable.getData();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../phprequests/saveMaterials.php",
        data: { "data": tableData,
                "endUserId": <?php echo $endUserId ?>},
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (res) {
            if (res.result === 'ok') {
                if(showAlert) alert('Saved data.');
            }
            else {
                if(showAlert) alert(res.errorMessage);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            if(showAlert) alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

In my PHP server, I will just receive the data, and save in in my DB:

```
<?php
    $materialsData = $_POST['data'];
    $endUserId = $_POST['endUserId'];
    //deal with materialsData
?>
```

materialsData is an array of objects (rows of the Handsontable), which have about 15 fields each (One for each column).

When I have a small number of rows, everything works as expected. However, after sending more than 80 rows at a time, I noticed my PHP is receiving only 72 items of the materialsData array, and the "endUserId" part of the data is not received as well.
Looks like, for some reason, only part of the data was sent to the server, or received by it.

Is there a limit for the data lenght I can send on this post request?
I checked max_post_size in my server, and it's set to 256MB.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` and `json_decode` would likely make your life a little easier.

Comment: Solved the problem by increasing max_input_vars in my php.ini file.

Comment: @JaredSmith, I thought about it too, but then noticed that even if the dataType is JSON, and the data is an object array, the server receives the object array perfectly.

Comment: `dataType` refers to the type of data you expect BACK from the server, not the type you're sending TO the server. My advice stands.

Comment: Yes, I realized my reference do dataType as JSON was irrelevant right now. But still, why should I care about using JSON.stringify() before sending the data, and then json_decode in the server, if the array is received in both ways? Is sending the JSON lighter/faster? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `JSON.stringify()` serializes object as a `json` string which is very easy to transmit, its just a string. `json_decode` will turn it back on the other end. You can use the reverse operations `JSON.parse()` and `json_encode()` to send data back to the browser. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem by **increasing max_input_vars** in my server's php.ini file

Since I had more than 1000 variables in the array, only part of them was received by the server!

Hope this helps someone!